# automating touch events ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, monkeytalk

For automated testing reasons, I want to generate low-level touch events programmatically. We are using MonkeyTalk, which abstracts to a higher level in many cases such that only taps seem to work properly when the app does not use gesture recognizers. I am trying to fix the swipe functionality, but am having trouble understanding what exactly I need to send to the touchesMoved method (touchesEnded and touchedBegan are relatively straightforward).